# Firefox for android - shortcut to open url in private tab

Tags: android, firefox, android-intent, safe-browsing

The firefox app for android offers an option to create a shortcut on your homescreen, that opens a specified url.

Is it possible to create such a shortcut, that opens the url in a new private tab, or to launch firefox in private browsing mode using java and intents?